# Excel VBA - Removing Text After Some Time

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to show some hint as text in cell for a few seconds as below.

```
    Dim text As String
    text = "Hello World"

    If Range("A1") = 1 Then 
        Range("B1") = text 
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        Range("B1") = ""
    End If
```

The code runs perfectly if the vba has only the above code but for my case, there is a big chunk of codes before this "Hint" function. Whenever the IF statement turns TRUE, my mouse cursor would turn into window's loading sign without cell B1 showing anything.

After 5 sec, "Hello World" would appears very briefly before cell B1 becomes empty again, just as what it was intended to do, but with the timing all messed up.

I know the hardware may be at fault here but is there any other way to go around this?

Comment: Did you turn off `ScreenUpdating`?

Comment: @K.Davis, no, if I turn off ScreenUpdating, cell B1 will show nothing at all, not even the brief appearance of "Hello World"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to diagnose your specific issue without seeing the above coding, but you can try something along these lines:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim text As String, iLoop As Integer
    text = "Hello World"

    If Range("A1") = 1 Then
        For iLoop = 1 To 5  '5 is the number of seconds to wait
            Range("B1") = text
            DoEvents
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Loop
        Range("B1") = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Though I'm not sure why the timer runs first without showing text in my code but by using DoEvents, it definitely retain the text in cell B1 as intended before erasing it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to deal with events - in the worksheet, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Range("A1") = 1 Then
        Range("B1") = "Hello world"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        Range("B1") = vbNullString
    End If

End Sub
```

Make sure that you have `Application.EnableEvents = True`, in oder to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

As the Application.Wait eats up the CPU to 100% ("*busy wait*"), it's better to use the Windows `Sleep`.

You have to put a declaration at the top of the code:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
```

Then, write a simple Sub like this:

```
Public Sub WaitSeconds(seconds As Integer)
    Dim WaitUntil As Date
    WaitUntil = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now)

    Do While Now < WaitUntil
        Sleep 100
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```